# Set different colors for alternante rows in Excel

Tags: javascript, excel

I want to set the background color of the rows in Excel. Starting from the third row, alternate rows should be colored in two different colors for the used range of cells. I'm creating the Excel from javascript.

Comment: just 2 colors. The header color will be hard coded.

Comment: yes, white and  any other color , for the used range.

Answer (score 0):

see excel ribbon: INSERT>Tables>Table

This will convert the selected range to be a excel "Table" AKA ListObject and will make the data in the excel sheet more manageable.  One property of the table is the alternate the background colour of each row.

Although you are using java to create the file, I would hope you would be able to take advantage of this feature (and other features the table object provides - like simplified formulas etc)

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code to find the mod and then used if else statement to color the altenatively.

```
if (row % 2 ===0)
{
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + (row + 1 +  offset)).Value=Number;
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("B" + (row + 1 + offset)).Value = Type;
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("C" + (row + 1 + offset)).Value = Code;
row=row+1;
}
else
{
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + (row + 1 +  offset)).Value=Number;
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("B" + (row + 1 + offset)).Value = Type;
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("C" + (row + 1 + offset)).Value = Code;
row=row+1;
}
}
offset=offset+1;
```

Thanks to all for the suggestions.